# Which way of setting something when it is null, is faster?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Which is faster in Java, and why?

```
try {
  object.doSomething()
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  if (object == null) {
    object = new .....;
    object.doSomething();
  } else throw e;
}
```

or

```
if (object == null) {
  object = new .....;
}
object.doSomething();
```

and why?

The code would be called often, and `object` is only `null` the first time it's called, so don't take the cost of the thrown `NPE`into account (it only happens once).

P.S. I know the second is better because of simplicity, readability, etc, and **I'd surely go for that in real software**. I know all about the evil of premature optimization, no need to mention it.
I'm merely curious about these little details.

Comment: In C# the first one is wrong because it destroys the stack trace. Is that also the case in Java?

Comment: Yes, it'd be better to wrap and re-throw the exception if there was a good reason to do so.  I think the code in the catch block is enough of a "handling" of the situation where I wouldn't rethrow.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: You mean when the exception is rethrown? No, the stack trace is unchanged then, fortunately. If it did change, a lot of my code would be much harder to debug.

Comment: If object is only null the first time it is called, then I don't understand the question.  In general, why worry about microoptimization? If you insist on microoptimization, why even bother testing for nullness - you know it is null.

Comment: @emory I don't know it's always null, I only know it is so the first time (so a check must be done)

Comment: @Bart so you know it null the first time, so microptimized code would look like object=new(...); object.doSomething(); for ( int i = 2; i < n ; i++ ) { object.doSomething(); } --- no need for any checks

Comment: @emory I said the code is called often, not it's called in a loop

Comment: While exceptions ARE extremely expensive when used, if you can avoid them there's no overhead whatsoever (ie you don't get any performance hit if no exception is thrown) - so if the code is called often enough (to offset the additional cost for the first exception) you'll see performance benefits, but then we're talking about one conditional and the JIT can do some pretty nifty things there anyway (eg it could notice that object isn't NULL and always use the normal case and deoptimize if the assumption turns out to be wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, version 1 is much slower when it explodes because creating Exceptions is quite expensive, but it is not faster than version 2 because the JVM must do the null check itself *anyway* so you're not saving anytime. The compiler is likely to optimize the code so it's no faster anyway.

Also Exceptions should be reserved for the exceptional. Initial state of null is not exceptional.

Use the lazy initialization pattern:

```
SomeClass getIt() {
    if (it == null)
        it = new SomeClass();
    return it;
}

...
getIt().someMethod();
```

Comment: But is it smart enough to optimize the second to do only 1 null check instead of 2? The first has just 1 check (except the first time it's called), and a try/catch of which I don't know the cost.

Comment: But +1 for answering the question instead of starting about premature optimization.

Answer (score 9):

You should absolutely use the latter way, not because it's faster, but because it's more idiomatic. Exceptions should *not* be used for control flow in your java programs.

this is purely anecdotal, but all the microbenchmarking I have ever done has shown that using exceptions for control flow won't be as performant as conditionals, although it's probably impossible to support this as a generalization and the JVM is very good at optimizing around things like this anyways, so YMMV.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Apart from the far better coding style, your latter observation is quite true. Exception handling is well exceptional and not that trivial. The JVM has to traverse the exception handlers looking for the correct one (even if we use the innermost, that's still more than 1 memory access). Also it should be noted that the JVM optimizer is way better at optimizing common coding paradigms, so usually the best way to get good performance is not to try anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about speed - look at the size of the code in the first snippet versus the second.

Is the simpler option the best one? Easiest to read, takes up less space, etc. You should strive for code simplicity first, and then worry about speed once you've measured something as slow.

Besides, think about what the runtime needs to do in order to determine that it needs to throw a `NullPointerException` - it has to check if the current reference is `null`. So even without measuring, it would logically make sense that performing the check yourself is simpler, rather than leaving it up to the JRE to make the check *and* create a `NullPointerException` *and* unwind the stack.

Comment: I know, and in a real program I'd always choose the second. I'm merely interested.

Comment: if you are curious from an academic perspective, then the best way to answer the question is set up a benchmark and measure it.

Comment: Its interesting from an academic, almost nerdy point of view. So, whats faster, a try block or an if statement? I am no VM expert but I would imagine it differs on JVM and OS versions, and hardware.

Comment: I might set up a benchmark, but if somebody already knows I don't need to. And if nobody already knows, I can share my results.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of speed, the first way is not good programming practice.  For example, what if `object` was not null but `object.doSomething()` resulted in the `NullPointerException`?

This is one reason why you should not use exceptions to control program flow!

Comment: No it *isn't* a good point - the OP code differentiates between the method causing the NPE and object being null and re-throws the NPE is the method caused it. Pay attention.

Comment: In that case, the program would have called `doSomething()` twice when it should have only needed to call it once to determine something was amiss. Which was my point.

Comment: @Peter: How is it called twice? The first call halts because of the NPE

Answer (score 1):

Check the [The Java Specialists' Newsletter - Issue 187 Cost of Causing Exceptions](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue187.html) for some interesting internal details.

Comment: Thanks, interesting article, but it talks about exceptions that are thrown often. Mine is thrown only once.

Answer (score 0):

a thrown exception (first example) is nearly always slower than normal control flow code (second example)

that aside the second is much cleaner and easier to understand

Comment: The exception would only get thrown once (when `object` is `null`) so that's negligible. Setting up the `try/catch` would be done every time though, if that matters.

Comment: @bart throwing is not simple compared to normal operation; throwing an exception requires scanning the call stack for finally blocks (and executing them) and the catch clause that will handle it

Comment: Yes but as I said, *it only happens once*, and is therefore negligible, compared to the millions of times (or something) the method is called when `object` is not `null`.

Comment: @bart the check will happen either way and the JIT will optimize it so it is only checked once, the lazy initialization pattern like in the question is common enough that it will be able to throw out the if branch once it has been called a few times

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say the second solution is faster. Not because I'm an expert on the JIT or VM but because it makes sense that a single branch-if-equal assembly-level routine is faster than looking up the object in memory, determining that it is null (the same test, I assume), throwing an exception and possibly mucking up the stack.

Comment: But looking up the object has to be done every time, and anything that only happens the first time (such as the exception being thrown) can be ignored.